How do i get rid this white background while page transition
You can see the problem here
I want the pages to follow one another like carousel but this white background on the video looks ugly and i can't get rid of it.
index.js:
<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>

App.js:
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}

Home.js:
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ y: "100%" }}
      animate={{ y: "0%" }}
      transition={{ bounce: 0, duration: 0.75, ease: "easeOut" }}
      exit={{ opacity: 1 }}
      data-pageName="home"
      className={styles.page}
    >
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

About.js:
const About = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ y: "100%" }}
      animate={{ y: "0%" }}
      exit={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ bounce: 0, duration: 0.75, ease: "easeOut" }}
      data-pageName="about"
      className={styles.page}
    >
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </motion.div>
  );
};


The transition is going to show whatever background is behind the transition;  you'll have to define something as the background;  ideally when you are transitioning between two alternating colors, you would set the background of one page to the color of the other, which would be hidden behind the transition at 100%.  Otherwise, you'll need some other background if you don't like the white.

Like @Claies said, you need something behind the transition.
If you migrate to a data router you can use the useNavigation hook to figure out what to load behind your next component.
const { state, location } = useNavigation()

Use state to figure out when a navigation is happening. You will likely need your background to linger for some time because otherwise the navigation will finish before the transition. You probably also want to cancel that lingering effect in case the navigation starts over.
Use location to figure out where you are navigating to, in order to set the correct background.
